# How OEI licence differ from OEM licence

Tags: licensing

How OEI licence differ from OEM licence? Can I buy OEI for existing computers additionaly? For, example, Windows Server CAL 2016 English 1pk DSP OEI 5 Clt Device CAL

ADD:
Simple answer would be: OEI is the OEM, because it can be purchased additionaly in case of Windows server is OEM. In other words: with OEI licence you can connect to OEM server.

Answer (score 3):

In essence, they are the same thing, but basically OEM is a license supplied
by Microsoft to a big computer manufacturing company that gets better quantity discount,
whereas OEI (aka DSP OEI or Delivery Service Partners Original Equipment Installation)
is for smaller manufacturers that buy fewer licenses and so get a lower
quantity discount (higher prices to customers).

OEI and OEM both have the same limitations on activation with hardware.
In some cases, OEM licenses will have the company name printed on the license,
whereas OEI ones won't.

Also, in most cases Microsoft does not provide direct user support for OEM licenses, as support should be from PC manufacturer, whereas they might do with OEI.